# PHP - Getting individual values from a linked array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an array that seems to have "linked" values.

When I print_r my array its giving me this:

```
Array ( [0] => Field1 [1] => Field2 [2] => Field3 [3] => 
Field4 [4] => Field5 [5] => Field6 [6] => Field7 [7] => Field8 ) 

Array ( [0] => VarA [1] => VarB [2] => VarC [3] => 
VarD [4] => VarE [5] => VarF < [6] => VarG [7] 
=> VarH) 

Array ( [0] => Var1 [1] => Var2 [2] => Var3 [3] => 
Var4 [4] => Var5 [5] => Var6 [6] => Var7 [7] => Var8)
```

So when I do:

```
echo $array[0];
```

It prints:

```
Field1VarAVar1
```

How can I access each value individually?

Comment: Are you sure you are posting your entire array structure? I only see three distinct arrays.

Comment: Is that echo in a loop?

Comment: @Terry thats from printing one array. Am handling a csv file, I'll add some code for context.

Comment: that's 3 arrays not 1. your not showing enough information

Comment: Try this echo $array[0][0];